# How can I pass data between two Chrome apps?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I have created two Chrome apps and I want to pass some data (string format) from one Chrome app to another Chrome app. Appreciate if someone can help me with showing the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an RTFM question.

From [Messaging documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging#external) (note that it mentions extensions, but it works for apps):

> In addition to sending messages between different components in your extension, you can use the messaging API to communicate with other extensions. This lets you expose a public API that other extensions can take advantage of.

You need to send messages using `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` (using app ID) and receive them using `chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal` event. If required, long-lived connections can also be established.

```
// App 1
var app2id = "abcdefghijklmnoabcdefhijklmnoab2";
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
  // This should fire even if the app is not running, as long as it is
  //   included in the event page (background script)
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(sender.id == app2id && request.data) {
      // Use data passed
      // Pass an answer with sendResponse() if needed
    }
  }
);

// App 2
var app1id = "abcdefghijklmnoabcdefhijklmnoab1";
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(app1id, {data: /* some data */},
  function(response) {
    if(response) {
      // Installed and responded
    } else {
      // Could not connect; not installed
      // Maybe inspect chrome.runtime.lastError
    }
  }
);
```